# Mocking framework in Windows Phone8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mocking, tdd

I just started development in Windows Phone 8 and need to write test cases using mocking framework. I am not sure about any framework in Windows Phone 8 that gives you mocking functionality.

Does anybody know any good mocking framework in Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 2):

We use [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) and it works pretty well.

Comment: do you build it yourself? the nuget package does not seem to support windows phone

Comment: We use the Moq.Silverlight.dll. I believe this page explains a similar setup to ours: http://wp.qmatteoq.com/unit-testing-in-windows-phone-8-asynchronous-operations-and-mocking/